# MongoDB match sub-child

Tags: mongodb

Suppose we have a MongoDB collection with items like

```
{
  "_id" : "f239tmmls03",
  "items" : {
    "id_0mgq95k3t" : {
      "value" : 591
    },
    "id_95jf3156w" : {
      "value" : 12
    }
  }
}
{
  "_id" : "959giwmgsr",
  "items" : {
    "id_kg384962" : {
      "value" : 9
    }
  }
}
```

Something like that.  Is there a simple way of, say, searching for documents with one or more items having a given value?  For example, a query like

```
db.the_collection.find({"items.?.value" : 12})
```

or something, which would return the first of the two example documents I gave.  Essentially, I'd like to be able to skip one or more layers of document, because they're keyed by some arbitrary string.

Answer (score 0):

As for as I know, even if it's a yes (which is not), it would be very hard to build an index on that. thus this kind of query would be very slow.

Is there any specific reason why you don't use an array?

```
{
  "_id" : "959giwmgsr",
  "items" : [{
      "id": "id_kg384962",
      "value" : 9
  }]
}
```

Comment: I don't know why we don't/didn't use an array, but there's hundreds of thousands of documents, now, so it's a bit late for such a measure, anyway, but thanks.